# Polymer SPA architecture

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, single-page-application, polymer-1.0

I want to create Polymer single page application. Layout is pretty common: navigation drawer with list of available pages and main section with toolbar (header) and main content. Pagination is made with neon-animated-pages.

The question is: how to properly design app structure and elements interaction for this use case? How can child pages (which are displayed by neon-animated-pages element) can affect main layout file?

For example I want to change text on header toolbar (it is located in index.html) according to currently selected page. Let's say I have page-main and page-auth elements. They both have property pageTitle and I want this text from currently selected page to be displayed in header.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common options for managing the sharing of data across a series of site-specific custom elements:

1. Create a `<my-app>` element that contains the site's data and elements.
2. Use `<template is="dom-bind">` to enable data binding across the elements.

Once you have either of those, you can expose `pageTitle` as an attribute or property and bind it to the header toolbar contents.

Comment: Is there any good way to do something like this: `<neon-animated-pages id="pages">...</neon-animated-pages>`
`pages.currentPage.pageTitle`?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a wrapper element that houses the current page/state your user is currently on.  When the user switches views, the wrapper should be notified, we will call this variable "A", which will display the selected view as well as displaying the correct text.